# Vue.js axios interceptor response 401

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I am getting this error on console: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'message') at eval.
This is my code in axios.js:

```
axiosIns.interceptors.response.use(
response => {
    if (response.message === 'Unauthenticated') {
        window.location = '/login'
    }

    return response
},
error => {
    if (error.response.message === 'Unauthenticated') {
        window.location = '/login'
    } else if (error.response.status === 401) {
        removeUserData()
        return Promise.reject(error)
    }
})
```

Comment: The error is here: ```error.response.message``` must actually be ```error.message```. I think. Have to know about the API response to be 100% sure.

Comment: @adibro500 I did this and it gave: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'status') at eval, on console. I used the same (error.message.response) at my previous project and it worked but i dont know why it is not working again. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Can you provide me the screenshot of the network -> response/preview tab? That will be easier. You can check that too yourself.

Comment: @adibro500 interesting this is i am not getting any response in network, error is shown only in console and that suprised me. Maybe i should review my codes from begining

Comment: The reason can be that the page is getting redirected to the `/login` route. Please try to check the `Preserve Log` option in the network tab and try.

Comment: @adibro500 u dont believe it worked, but unfortunately routes.js is not working :(. Anyways thanks for ur help can u vote up so others who are facing this problem can see and learn, thanks bro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to replace `response.message` and `error.response.message` by `response.statusText` and `error.response.statusText`.

Answer (score -1):

Can you show us how your client is used? My guess is your call is a promise with no "catch". Don't forget you rejected that promise earlier:

```
return Promise.reject(error)
```